# mapping items into a list

Tags: list, dictionary, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a project, working with JavaScript/Vue, where I'm writing out ingredients by mapping each item, joined by `", "`. Instead, I would like to write each item out as a list, but am unsure how to go about doing this. The code I have right now looks like this:

```html
<li>
  {{ order.ingredients.map(item=>item["ingredient_"+ lang]).join(", \n")}} 
</li>
```

Is there a good way of doing this?

Comment: when you say write each item out as a 'list', do you mean list as in `<ul><li></li></ul>`?

Comment: right now it prints it out like: ingredient1, ingredient2, ingredient3, ingredient4 etc..
I would like for it to be like:
ingredient1

ingredient2

ingredient3

ingredient4

instead.

Comment: and what do you want the end result to be?

Comment: it's supposed to be each item on a new line put can't write that here in the comment section-

Comment: ok, I've made you an answer below with a viewable example. Just press the run code snippet button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure what your HTML structure is, but one way to do it using the [v-for directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) would be like this.

```js
const vue = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      order: {
        ingredients: ['orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'banana']
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="(ingredient,index) in order.ingredients" :key="index">
    <li> {{ingredient}} </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks you! I just added {{item["ingredient_" + lang]}} to the code and it worked. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Glad it helped, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="(item,i) in order.ingredients" :key="i">{{"ingredient_"+item.lang}}</li>
</ul>
```

Check out the docs, on the `v-for` directive allows inline iteration over arrays and then you have access to each element which you can display/display and manipulate.